# Split a Comma Separated Value of a Field

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to import a CSV for a shop, with a subset of data from an existing CSV file. I need to split one item from a column (column 3, `category_id`) that contains multiple comma-separated values, then combine it with one other column (`Product_id`) to produce multiple rows in the import CSV.  See the following examples.

**Original CSV**

```
Product_id;article_id;category_id;
"1";"0001";"2,4,6"
```

Need it into a **new CSV file**

```
Product_id;category_id    
"1";"2"    
"1","4"    
"1","6"
```

I tried just the `fegetcsv` function to read in the CSV and to printout the whole into an array but I have no idea what to do next.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen ("articles.csv","r");
while ( ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE ) {
$column3[] = $data[3];
}
fclose ($handle);
//edit:
print_r($column3);
?>
```

I get:

```
Array ([0] => category_id [1] => 1 [2] => 0001 [3] => 2,4,6
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you want to do this in php? Is it a one time thing?

Comment: to make an automated import solution /cronjob for client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$csvData = file('articles.csv');
$matches = array();
$output = "";
foreach($csvData as $csvLine) {
    if(preg_match('/"(.+)";".+";"(.+)"/', $csvLine, $matches))
    {
        $numbers = explode(',', $matches[2]);
        foreach($numbers as $number) {
            $output .= "\"{$matches[1]}\";\"{$number}\"" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for anwser, but the output  should be  splitted  the 2nd  field of the output into 3 new lines.

Comment: i think i need explode for this or something to extract the values into seperated lines

Comment: Give that update a try, just doing this off top of my head -- hope there are no typos...

Comment: thats really cool it works , just in one line but it helps alot =) tyvm

Comment: hi the "\n" end ot output should normaly extract itinto new line but i got it only in one line. made i something wrong ?

Comment: use $output .= "\"{$matches[1]}\";\"{$number}\"" . PHP_EOL; instead, might fix it if you're on a windows machine. Also are you outputting to browser or writing to a text file then reading it in something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94515/discussion-between-midri-and-da-unknown).